# Filter and Group multiple DataSets in spark java

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am very new to spark.The below is the requirement am getting to

```
1st RDD

empno first-name last-name
0        fname     lname
1        fname1    lname1

2nd rdd
empno dept-no dept-code
0       1        a
0       1        b
1       1        a
1       2        a

3rd rdd
empno history-no address
0       1            xyz
0       2            abc
1       1            123
1       2            456
1       3            a12
```

I have to generate a file combining all the RDDs for each employee, and the average emp-count is 200k

Desired output:

```
seg-start emp-0
seg-emp 0-fname-lname
seg-dept 0-1-a
seg-dept 0-1-b
seg-his 0-1-xyz
seg-his 0-2-abc
seg-end emp-0
seg-start emp-1
......
seg-end emp-1
```

How can I achieve this by combining RDDs? Please note that the data is not written straight forward as it was shown here, we are converting data to business valid format(ex:- e0xx5fname5lname is 0-fname-lname), so need help from the experts here, as the current batch program runs for hours to write data, thinking of using spark to process this efficiently.